# Can't import sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have successfully installed `sklearn`. However, when I run `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score`, it givies an error `ImportError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score'`

`sklearn` version is `0.17`

`numpy` version is `1.8.2`

`scipy` version is `0.13.3`

Btw I'm using `python3`. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`accuracy_score` is a function, not a module, you have to import it **from** a module, thus

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score #works
print(accuracy_score([1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]))
```

gives

```
0.333333333333
```

as expected.

and not

```
import sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score #error
```

Comment: Ok. But still have an error `print accuracy_score(labels_test, pred)` and  this `^` pointing to `accuracy_score` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: you are using **python 3**, thus print requires parenthesis, you can't call `print x` in python 3, but `print(x)` instead

Comment: Thnx, didn't know we have to use parenthesis in python 3

Answer (score 2):

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

print(accuracy_score([1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]))
```

*Note*: it's `metrics` not `metric`

Answer (score 1):

```
    from sklearn import metrics
    print(metrics.accuracy_score([2, 1, 1], [2, 0, 1]))
```

You can also go with  this

Answer (score -1):

It works with metric**s** for me

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics